# Bootstrap expand/collapse not closing the last open item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Stack overflow community

I have used bootstrap to expand/collapse in multiple places.

I need to make sure only 1 open at a time n rest all close (which is happening currently) but when I am clicking on opened one it's not closing.

I don't want to switch to the accordion.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```js
$(".supporting-link").on('click', function() {
        $(".collapse").removeClass("show");
        $(".supporting-link").attr("aria-expanded","false");
    });
```

```css
li {
list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="search-result">
                                    <div class="searchresult-item">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
                                                    <div class="search-icon">
                                                        
                                                        <br>
                                                        Icon
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-12">
                                                    <ul class="mt-1">
                                                        <li><a href="" class="item-link">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                                        <li class="item-desc">Dummy Description</li>
                                                         English</li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link mr-4 pr-4" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLots2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLots">
                                                            Supporting Lots
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLangs2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLangs">
                                                            Supporting Languages
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLots2">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <ul class="supportingLots-list">
                                            <li>10091234</li>
                                        </ul>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLangs2">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Chinese</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Danish</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>German</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="search-result">
                                    <div class="searchresult-item">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
                                                    <div class="search-icon">
                                                        
                                                        <br>
                                                        Icon
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-12">
                                                    <ul class="mt-1">
                                                        <li><a href="" class="item-link">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                                        <li class="item-desc">Dummy Description</li>
                                                         English</li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link mr-4 pr-4" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLots3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLots">
                                                            Supporting Lots
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLangs3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLangs">
                                                            Supporting Languages
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLots3">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <ul class="supportingLots-list">
                                            <li>10091234</li>
                                        </ul>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLangs3">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Chinese</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Danish</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>German</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="search-result">
                                    <div class="searchresult-item">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
                                                    <div class="search-icon">
                                                        
                                                        <br>
                                                        Icon
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-12">
                                                    <ul class="mt-1">
                                                        <li><a href="" class="item-link">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                                        <li class="item-desc">Dummy Description</li>
                                                         English</li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link mr-4 pr-4" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLots4" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLots">
                                                            Supporting Lots
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLangs4" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLangs">
                                                            Supporting Languages
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLots4">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <ul class="supportingLots-list">
                                            <li>10091234</li>
                                        </ul>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLangs4">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Chinese</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Danish</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>German</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="search-result">
                                    <div class="searchresult-item">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
                                                    <div class="search-icon">
                                                        
                                                        <br>
                                                        Icon
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-12">
                                                    <ul class="mt-1">
                                                        <li><a href="" class="item-link">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                                        <li class="item-desc">Dummy Description</li>
                                                         English</li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link mr-4 pr-4" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLots5" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLots">
                                                            Supporting Lots
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLangs5" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLangs">
                                                            Supporting Languages
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLots5">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <ul class="supportingLots-list">
                                            <li>10091234</li>
                                        </ul>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLangs5">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Chinese</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Danish</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>German</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="search-result">
                                    <div class="searchresult-item">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
                                                    <div class="search-icon">
                                                        
                                                        <br>
                                                        Icon
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-12">
                                                    <ul class="mt-1">
                                                        <li><a href="" class="item-link">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                                        <li class="item-desc">Dummy Description</li>
                                                         English</li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link mr-4 pr-4" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLots6" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLots">
                                                            Supporting Lots
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a class="supporting-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLangs6" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLangs">
                                                            Supporting Languages
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLots6">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <ul class="supportingLots-list">
                                            <li>10091234</li>
                                        </ul>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="supportingLangs6">
                                      <div class="card card-body">
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Chinese</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>Danish</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="supportingLang-list">
                                            <span>German</span>
                                            <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: here `toggle()` will help. I can make a decision for you.

Comment: sure if you can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already relying on Bootstrap's collapse component why not utilize its built-in transition methods?  In this case calling `.collapse('hide')` on any of your `.collapse` classes will cause them to collapse back in.

```js
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="search-result">
  <div class="searchresult-item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <div class="search-icon">Icon</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-12">
        <ul class="mt-1">
        <li><a href="" class="item-link">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li class="item-desc">Dummy Description</li>
        <li>English</li>
        <li>
          <a class="supporting-link mr-4 pr-4" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLots1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLots1">Supporting Lots</a>
          <a class="supporting-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLangs1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLangs1">Supporting Languages</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="supportingLots1">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <ul class="supportingLots-list">
       <li>10091234</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="supportingLangs1">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <div class="supportingLang-list">
        <span>Chinese</span>
        <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
      </div>

      <div class="supportingLang-list">
        <span>Danish</span>
        <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
      </div>

      <div class="supportingLang-list">
        <span>German</span>
        <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="search-result">
  <div class="searchresult-item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <div class="search-icon">Icon</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-12">
        <ul class="mt-1">
        <li><a href="" class="item-link">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li class="item-desc">Dummy Description</li>
        <li>English</li>
        <li>
          <a class="supporting-link mr-4 pr-4" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLots2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLots2">Supporting Lots</a>
          <a class="supporting-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#supportingLangs2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="supportingLangs2">Supporting Languages</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="supportingLots2">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <ul class="supportingLots-list">
       <li>10091234</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="supportingLangs2">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <div class="supportingLang-list">
        <span>Chinese</span>
        <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
      </div>

      <div class="supportingLang-list">
        <span>Danish</span>
        <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
      </div>

      <div class="supportingLang-list">
        <span>German</span>
        <span><a href="">Complete PDF</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```